# Rewrite URL's in Joomla menus

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, menu, url-rewriting

My group and I are working on a school project with Joomla. We have custom php to list "articles" from our database, and the PHP is getting its data from `$_GET` (from the url.)
Skip to the question:

This is what we have:

```
example.com/articles/menu
```

We want:

```
example.com/articles/menu?q=something+something
```

How do you rewrite / add text to url, so we get that format?
We are using the school server, so we have no admin-rights on the server.
I have tried mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess, but without success.
The server is running windows.
We are using joomla 2.5

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php/articles/menu?q=something+something$ /index.php/articles/menu [L]
```

Comment: You forgot to post your `RewriteRule` code. Use the *edit* button to add it to your question.

Comment: Did you make a custom router?

Comment: @Elin, what do you mean by Custom router?
We are at school, the only info about the server I know is that it is a windows server.

Comment: WHen you write a Joomla component part of that should be a router and also a route helper. That is how you manage URLs in Joomla. Please look at any core extension such as contact to see examples of this. I say contact becauase content has a highly customized one and weblinks is special in its own way.  You might look at com_tags in the 3.1 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/articles/menu$ index.php/articles/menu?q=something+something [QSA,L]
```

And that will do the job.

Hey by the way, try to google a bit, there are tons of answers for such simple things **`;)`**

Checkout the right documentation about QSA directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: @oliver-pons 
Hi! I have googled a bit, and the server does no seem to make the changes :) So its not working in .htaccess, what so ever. Lame school server...
I fixed in with Javascript.
Thanks anyways :)